# 240v in with 240 and 120 out of a timer?

Tags: electrical, pool, timer, 240

We just got our pool up. Opened the salt generator packaging and it is a 220/240v appliance, our pump is 115v with a pre installed plug. They need to be on the same timer. I have read until my head hurts… Does anyone know if I can run 240 into a timer and have one output run to the salt generator from the timer at 220/240 and another to a 120v outlet for the pump to plug into? What model timer? their diagrams are awful for merely semi handy people

Comment: What is the amp draw (or VA) of each of the appliances in question?

Comment: 12 for the pump and the salt generator company said it only uses 3 I was going to do a double pole 20A

Comment: If you can't find a timer designed for 120-0-120 volt service, use a 120 V **AC** relay. A common 120 volt timer could control a power relay for the 240 V circuit, with the coil of the relay in parallel with the 120 V pump.

Comment: Is the pump **only** plug-in? Or can it be hardwired? Many devices (e.g., disposals, dishwashers) can be set up either way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the amps you state are accurate, that should be fine... almost.

You will have 15A load on one pole and 12A load on the other.

Despite totaling 15A, you will need a 20A circuit, breaker and wire.  That is because you are only allowed to plan to load circuits to 80% with some exception. 80% of 20A is 16A, which is fine.

You will need 4-wire hot-hot-neutral-ground wiring from the panel through the timer to the 120V appliance.  The neutral bypasses a 240V timer.

There is only one snag.   You are not allowed to have this specific combination: *"the 12A load is hardwired, yet the 3A load uses a cord-and-plug connection"*.   That is because receptacles are not allowed on circuits where the hardwired load speaks for >50% of the circuit ampacity (20A).

All of this needs GFCI protection, the farther from the pool the better. It might be fed out of a pool panel that has GFCI protection already.  If not, the only way to protect this split-phase combination of loads is with a GFCI circuit breaker in the supplying panel.

Comment: *"the 12A load is hardwired, yet the 3A load uses a cord-and-plug connection"* Actually, it is the reverse. OP stated **our pump is 115v with a pre installed plug** + **12 for the pump**. So that's 3A hard-wired, 12A receptacle. Of course, it may be possible to hard-wire the pump - which may be preferable for a bunch of reasons. Though plug-in has the advantage of getting a "free" convenience receptacle out of the deal.